# Tag para "Redes"

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags

Não seria interessante termos uma tag "**Redes**" ou "**Network**" no SOPT?

Por exemplo este [Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6828/e-possivel-duas-aplicacoes-se-comunicarem-em-uma-rede-ad-hoc) se enquadra bem nessa tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com certeza.

Vou criar a tag.

**EDIT:**

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/redes/info